# I want to find any particular person name in my database

Tags: sql

I've one database and I try to find the solution for my one query.

I want to find the 5th person name who earn a max salary in my database. so can I do

For example this is my execute query. you can see 7 people name but i want to see only 5th person name  like only 'Mahesh"

my table is like that

```
FirstName  varchar (45),
LastName varchar (45),
Birthdate datetime,
position varchar (35),
DOJ datetime,
DeptID int,
Salary decimal (10,2)
```

and this is my execute query. you can see 7 people name but i want to see only 5th person name  like only 'Mahesh"

```
Salary      Name
90000.00    Amita
90000.00    Carla
89500.00    Sarah
89000.00    Gunjan
85000.00    **Mahesh**
96000.00    John
86000.00    Charles
```

So my question is 
I want to find the only one person name and salary from my data who earn 5th max salary.

Comment: Perhaps you should finish writing your question first.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to order them by salary value and find the 5th from the top?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I update my question so now can you help me for that

Comment: @GUNJAN you need to make sure you're explaining your question properly. You may want to read up on windowing functions, but you need some sort of order to your data, the data you have given has not obvious order. what decides that Mahesh is 5th in the list?

Comment: Mahesh is the person who got the 5th highest salary but you see I've seven people list so I want only Mahesh name as a 5th person not all of them.

Comment: @GUNJAN Mahesh doesn't have the 5th highest salary though, he actually has the lowest salary in your list? Also how do you want to handle ties, two people have a salary of 90000. Do they have the 2nd and 3rd highest salaries, or only the 2nd highest?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the user with the 5th highest salary, you could use an embedded query.

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM (SELECT TOP 5 *
      FROM YourTable
      ORDER BY Salary DESC) tmp
ORDER BY tmp.Salary
```

Or if you want to include ties.

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE Salary = (SELECT TOP 1 Salary
                FROM (SELECT TOP 5 Salary
                      FROM YourTable
                      ORDER BY Salary DESC) tmp
                ORDER BY tmp.Salary)
```